# What happens if a std::thread calls joinable on itself?

Tags: c++, multithreading, std

I am having problems since I made changes in my program and it might be due to a thread calling joinable on itself. What exacly happens in this situation?

**EDIT:**
I did some debugging, and the problme is Joinable method.

```
std::mutex threadMutex;
std::thread tAudioProcessingThread;

void getLock()
{
    if (tAudioProcessingThread.joinable())
        threadMutex.lock(); 
}

void releaseLock()
{
    if (tAudioProcessingThread.joinable())
        threadMutex.unlock();   
}
```

The functions      `getLock()`      and     `releaseLock()` are called from the two existing threads.
I had problems calling the    `threadMutex.lock()`and `threadMutex.unlock()`  functions before the thread was created, so I had to make these alternative functions, so that the locks only get called when the thread exists.

Comment: very likely either undefined or deadlocking....

Comment: We cannot divine the answer without a _complete_ testcase.

Comment: To handle locks properly, you should consider using [`lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)'s, instead of rolling your own stuff there. BTW if the thread doesn't actually run, why are you bothering about locking/unlocking the mutex?!?

Comment: You shouldn't have had the original problem with mutexes not working before the threads were created... how are you creating/destroying these threads and mutexes?

Comment: "What happens if a std::thread calls joinable on itself?" `joinable` returns `true`. Are you by any chance trying to unlock your `mutex` in a thread other than the thread that locked it? Because that is not allowed.

Comment: @Casey If it happens that thread A tries to unlock a lock acquired by thread B, will that cause a deadlock or what will happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thread cannot `join()` itself, but there's nothing wrong with a thread calling `joinable()` on itself.

All `t.joinable()` does is test `t.get_id() != std::thread::id{}` so it makes no difference which thread you call it from.

Answer (score 0):

Cameron was right, my mistake was elsewhere in the code, so that those functions are not necessary and the locking gets done properly.

@πάντα ῥεῖ: I had locks on functions that were called before and after the creation of the thread, so I had to put the locks there.

PS: Can't comment yet, thats why there are so many edits and so on...

Thanks guys